# Do we need [troubleshooting] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There is currently a [troubleshooting](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/troubleshooting) tag which has 29 questions and a tag wiki excerpt of:

> A form of problem solving, often applied to repair failed products or
>   processe [sic]

Is it needed, or a candidate for burnination?

Comment: I think we have enough votes to start burninating the [tag:troubleshooting] tag.

Comment: The [tag:troubleshooting] tag has now been burninated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that this tag is redundant for this site. I feel that the majority of the (now over 85,000) questions on this site deal with troubleshooting of one sort or another.

Since there are only 29 questions tagged with it, I say it should be burninated.

Comment: I agree - this is a trouble-shooting site.  Trouble-shooting could be implied for most questions so is an unnecessary tag.

Comment: Besides being a meta tag...